# finite dimensional $C^*$ subalgebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given any $C^*$-algebra $A$  (not necessarily unital),can we construct a nonzero  finite dimensional $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Every finite dimensional $C^*$-algebra is a von Neumann algebra, because it is a Banach dual space. $W^*$ algebras contain many projections -- in particular the range projections of their elements -- but there are $C^*$-algebras with no projections.